# Executing Perl from R - perlQuote/shQuote?

Tags: r, perl

I'm trying to run some Perl from R using `system`: simply assigning a string (provided in R) to a variable and echoing it. (the `system` call executes in `/bin/sh`)

```
echo <- function (string) {
    cmd <- paste(shQuote(Sys.which('perl')),
                 '-e',
                 shQuote(sprintf("$str=%s; print $str", shQuote(string))))
    message(cmd)
    system(cmd)
}
# all fine:
# echo('hello world!')
# echo("'")
# echo('"')
# echo('foo\nbar')
```

However, if I try to `echo` a backslash (or indeed any string ending in a backslash), I get an error:

```
> echo('\\')
'/usr/bin/perl' -e "\$str='\\'; print \$str"
Can't find string terminator "'" anywhere before EOF at -e line 1.
```

(Note: the backslash in front of the `$` is fine as this protects `/bin/sh` from thinking `$str` is a shell variable).

The error is because *Perl* is interpreting the last `\'` as an embedded quote mark within `$str` as opposed to an escaped backslash. In fact, to get perl to echo a backslash I need to do

```
> echo('\\\\')
'/usr/bin/perl' -e "\$str='\\\\'; print \$str"
\ # <-- prints this
```

That is, I need to escape my backslashes for *Perl* (in addition to me escaping them in R/bash).

**How can I ensure in `echo` that the string the user enters is the string that gets printed? i.e. the only level of escaping that is needed is on the R level?**

i.e. is there some sort of `perlQuote` function analagous to `shQuote`? Should I just manually escape all backslashes in my `echo` function? Are there any other characters I need to escape given?

Comment: (I am attempting to make a `cowsay` package for R to combine with the `fortunes` package, so the question is for a good cause! ;))

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't generate code. That's hard. Instead, pass the argument as an argument:

```
echo <- function (string) {
    cmd <- paste(shQuote(Sys.which('perl')),
                 '-e', shQuote('my ($str) = @ARGV; print $str;'),
                 shQuote(string))
    message(cmd)
    system(cmd)
}
```

(You could also use an environment variable.)

(I've never used or even seen R code before, so pardon any syntax errors.)

Answer (score 3):

The following seems to work.
In Perl, I use `q//` instead of quotes to avoid problems with the shell quotes.

```
perlQuote <- function(string) {
  escaped_string <- gsub("\\\\", "\\\\\\\\", string)
  escaped_string <- gsub("/", "\\/", escaped_string)
  paste("q/", escaped_string, "/", sep="")
}
echo <- function (string) {
    cmd <- paste(shQuote(Sys.which('perl')),
                 '-le',
                 shQuote(sprintf("$str=%s; print $str", perlQuote(string))))
    message(cmd)
    system(cmd)
}
echo(1)
echo("'"); echo("''"); echo("'\""); echo("'\"'")
echo('"'); echo('""'); echo('"\''); echo('"\'"'); 
echo("\\"); echo("\\\\")
```